# querySelectorAll where class does not contain 'hide'

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

```
document.querySelectorAll('.giftUpsell-offer-desc + a')
```

Returns 3 a elements:

```
[
<a href=​"https:​/​/​www.qa.example.com" class=​"button button--primary button--wide u-hide" someattribute="fish">​
                    Extend & Save
                  ​</a>​, <a href=​"www.qa.example.com" class=​"button button--primary button--wide u-hide" someattribute="cats">​
                    Extend & Save
                  ​</a>​, <a href=​"www.qa.example.com" class=​"button button--primary button--wide" someattribute="dogs">​
                    Extend & Save
                  ​</a>​
]
```

I need to find the value of "someattribute" where the element is currently visible. I know the element with class attribute not containing "hide" is the one I want.

How could I edit my above selector to return this specific `<a>` element? In this example the one for dogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`:not(<selector>)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class:

```
.giftUpsell-offer-desc + a:not(.u-hide)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a tweak to make the logic to "contains" rather than equals .u-hide?

Comment: @DougFir `:not(.u-hide)` selector means "does not contain a `u-hide` class"

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:not` pseudoselector:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.giftUpsell-offer-desc + a:not(.u-hide)');
console.log(els);
```

```html
<div class="giftUpsell-offer-desc"></div>
<a href="https:​/​/​www.qa.example.com" class="button button--primary button--wide u-hide" someattribute="fish">Extend &amp; Save</a>
<div class="giftUpsell-offer-desc"></div>
<a href="www.qa.example.com" class="button button--primary button--wide u-hide" someattribute="cats">Extend &amp; Save</a>
<div class="giftUpsell-offer-desc"></div>
<a href="www.qa.example.com" class="button button--primary button--wide" someattribute="dogs">Extend &amp; Save</a>
```